# method missing from reactive extentions

Tags: system.reactive, eventaggregator

I am trying to implement event aggregator using RX(Reactive extensions) here is code am am using, but 
**subject.AddDisposable** method is missing. can anyone help me? maybe it is old version so in new version of Rx this method was removed? if this is the case than what is the right way to implement this?

```
 if (_observablesByTypeKey.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                Tuple<object, object> tuple = _observablesByTypeKey[key];
                stream = (IObservable<T>)tuple.Item2;
            }
            else
            {
                Type specificSubjectType = typeof(Subject<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(T) });
                var subject = (Subject<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(specificSubjectType, new object[] { });

                var removeEventStreamFromCache = Disposable.Create(
                    () =>
                        {
                            lock (_observablesByTypeKeyLock)
                            {
                                _observablesByTypeKey.Remove(key);
                            }
                        }
                    );

                stream = subject.AddDisposable(removeEventStreamFromCache).Publish().RefCount();

                var tuple = new Tuple<object, object>(subject, stream);
                _observablesByTypeKey.Add(key, tuple);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
stream = subject.AddDisposable(removeEventStreamFromCache).Publish().RefCount();
```

with

```
stream = Observable.Create(observer => 
  new CompositeDisposable(
    subject.Subscribe(observer),
    removeEventStreamFromCache));
stream.Publish().RefCount();
```